# Why the query result of Time and Numeric data type is strange?

Tags: postgresql, flutter

I am trying to query a Postgres DB from my flutter app. The query result for date and numeric data type in Postgres DB shows up in a list form. Can anybody help me understand why the values are turned into a list for date and numeric type? Here is my dart code.

```
import 'package:postgres/postgres.dart';
void main(List<String> arguments) async{
final conn = PostgreSQLConnection(
.....
);

await conn.open();
  print("Connected");

var results = await conn.query("select s_id, r_time, quantity from table;");
print(results);
```

The I table have looks like this:

```
s_id      r_time    quantity
4850     13:40:00     8.5
```

And here is the output I get:

```
[[4850, [0, 0, 0, 11, 116, 140, 108, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 8, 19, 136]]]
```

Anybody?

Comment: Just in case someone comes across the same problem, you can simply typecast the numeric value to REAL and DateTime to TEXT. It may not be efficient but serves the purpose and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what problem is

It should be with `datatype` if the error is from `dart` side

or

`Character set` if the error is from `PostgreSQL` side

Comment: I realized already that it was problem-related to typecast. I am able to return the correct value of the quantity column which is of numeric type but still could not retrieve the time column correctly.